# Jquery to remove item from table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table

[image: Image of the table here]

I have a drop down item in my system which builds a table of options on click , I would like to inject some Jquery that will remove some of the items in the list here is a example of one of the items created called (training)

```
<td class="ui-crmPopup-trigger" onclick="parent.Setopit_productid('Training','2','/CRM1/CustomPages/Products/ProductsSummary.asp?SID=94266470236396&amp;F=&amp;J=Products/ProductsSummary.asp&amp;Key58=2&amp;Prod_ProductId=2','Products','');$crmPopupParent.oPopupopit_productid.hide();">Training</td>
```

Can anyone help in what the code would look like? Sorry if I have missed some key info.

Comment: hey Rory, it looks to me that you need to remove a table cell. As you call an item. If this is true, you realize that this action will break your table layout causing the child cells of the row to change in size or position. Do you mean to remove the entire row or just replace the contents on the cell?

Comment: Hi Rory I added a screen print of some more of the table , I see what your saying maybe a easy solution would be to update some of the items to say 'unavailable' I'm open to ideas All the best

Comment: Please don't use images to show code. Use text to show code. Also look at creating a [mcve].

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this if all you're wanting to do is remove some text.

https://plnkr.co/edit/WTZu33hxKJaiGcK5TESM

```
$('.remove-on-click').on('click', function(){
    $(this).text('');
});
```

Or something like this,

```
$('.remove-on-load').text('');
```